# Problem getting in laravel HMVC framework related to session

Tags: php, laravel

When i try to access the session variable from another module's controller in laravel HMVC framework, the session variable shows null. I can not access the session from a controller, which is loaded from the  default controller of this framework. As for example,

**app/Https/Controllers**
Controller.php (Default controller of Laravel hmvc framework)

**app/Modules/Frontend/Https/Controllers**
Frontend.php

I can not access the session from "index" function of Frontend controller, which is stored in index function of Controller.php

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
    use Session;
    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
        public function index(){
            Session::put('name','MY NAME AVISHEK');
            Session::put('name1','MY NAME AVISHEK');
            Session::put('name2','MY NAME AVISHEK');
            Session::put('name3','MY NAME AVISHEK');
            Session::put('name4','MY NAME AVISHEK');
            Session::save();
            return view('welcome');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Frontend:

```
    namespace Frontend\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Session; 
    class Frontend extends Controller
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
        public function index(){
          dd(Session::all());
        }
    }
```

Comment: would need to see the routing to the controller

Comment: web.php file    <?php
Route::get('/frontend', 'Frontend\Http\Controllers\Frontend@index');
Route::get('/frontend/submit_data', 'Frontend\Http\Controllers\Frontend@abc');
?>

Comment: do you have a route that points to that **Base** Controller, `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` at it's `index` method and you have hit that route at some point?  You calling `Frontend@index` does not cause the parent `index` method to be called. It is overridden by your `index` method you made.

Comment: Never use ?> at the end of your code it could break it entirely

Comment: Where does this `Session` class come from? There should be a wrapper in Laravel that you should use instead of some other class

Comment: @NicoHaase its the Session Facade

Comment: Under routes folder web.php file points to the base controller. i.e. Route::get('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\Controller@index');